# How to reload a page on ajax call with clearing form fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, forms

Whenever ajax is called the page should be reloaded but all fields of forms should not get cleared on page-load

**my form**

```
<form method='post'>
 <input type='text' placeholder='product'/>
 <input type='number' placeholder='cost'/>
 <input type='number' placeholder='tax'/>
 <button type='button' id="cust_tax"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#cust_tax">Custom tax</button>
<input type='number' placeholder='new tax' id="cust_tax" class="collapse"/>
<input type='button' class='apply_tax'>New tax add</button>
<input type='submit'/>
</form>
```

when user click on custom tax there is a ajax call which save new_tax in database and it gets automatically added in list.

my ajax

```
$(".tax_apply").click(function() {
 var tax_name = document.getElementById("tax_name").value;
 var tax_value = document.getElementById("tax_value").value;
 ajaxPost('/myurl',{'user':user,'tax_name':tax_name,'tax_value':tax_value},function(result){
                    alert('new tax added');
                //reload page
                    });
});
```

now whenever ajax is called and user add new tax it should reload the page but form fields which he have entered should not get cleared

Comment: Why _it should reload the page_ ?

Comment: due to some backed issues which is not resolvable

Comment: I think you should be posting/asking/solving that issue instead of asking this patch!

Comment: no the official document also don't support that type of issue

Comment: Well, I strongly disagree with you about reloading the page but to solve this current issue, If your app has login/authentication, use `select query` with user id to access last inserted record of the user....

Comment: how to do it using javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you could do is attach an event listener to your form fields, that save the typed content to an object in [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp), Then on page load you could retrieve that content and put it back into the respective fields.

Here's an example of what you could potentially do.

```
$(myCollectionOfFields).keyup(function(){
    $(myFormFields).each(function(){    
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var value = $(this).val();
       localStorage.setItem(id, value);

    });   
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(myFormFields).each(function(){    
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var value = localStorage.getItem(id);

        $(this).val(value);

    }); 
});
```

I feel like I have to point out that this feels like an error prone solution(e.g. not every user will allow localStorage), and that I would address the backend issue you mentioned instead of using this approach.

But it could do the job in theory.